# Delete duplicates of a list whithout using using a secondary list

Tags: python

I have an exercise for my homeworks where I need to write a program that takes a list of integers as input, and returns the same list without any duplicate numbers.
The first idea that came to my mind is a loop using another list to compare with the first one, but we are not allowed to use another list.

Comment: Well, if you are not allowed to use auxiliary storage, you are going to have to rely on mutator methods like `.remove` or `del my_list[i]` Try something then ask a question if you run into problems, providing your [mcve]. Otherwise, this is too broad.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to StackOverflow. Right now, your question is kinda generic, since we have no idea of what you've tried so far. I highly recomend you post your attempts so far. Also, this can be useful for asking about homework: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Note, your first instinct was on the right track, but generally you would use a `set` as auxilliary storage in this case, because then you can remove duplicate in linear time!

Comment: Thank's for your answers, It finally worked perfectly with   list(set())   . Pretty sure that's not what my teachers wanted me to do, since they always want us to use math with ugly loops instead of built-in fonctions (which is kinda stupid in my opinion) but anyway thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `set`

```
s=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a']
s=list(set(s))
print(s)
>>> ['b', 'c', 'd', 'a']
```

Well, as for the comments, you can use OrderedDict

```
from collections import OrderedDict
s=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a']
print(list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(s)))
```

Comment: I imagine if you are not allowed to use another list you are not allowed to use a `set`, but even if you were, this would then become a clear duplicate.

Comment: This solution uses, even if implicitly, another list. :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can cast the list to a set and the cast that back to a list.

```
l = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
s = set(l)
list_without_duplicates = list(s)
```